# How to interpolate in a ruby method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to interpolate in a method name?
I'm trying to make this work `def "cancel_#{appointment.id}"` but having no luck. thanks

Comment: The question I have is why not simply do `def cancel_appointment(appointment_id); end` ?

Comment: @3limin4t0r, I don't understand your point. If `appointment.id #=> 'cat'` the OP wants to define an instance method `cancel_cat`, no?

Comment: @CarySwoveland The question is tagged with `ruby-on-rails`, so I assumed `appointment` is an `ActiveRecord::Base` instance. Say you've 100 appointments, would you want the methods `cancel_1`, `cancel_2`, `cancel_3`, `...`, `cancel_100`? It seems easier to call something like `cancel_appointment(1)` and have just one single method for this.

Comment: @3limin4t0r, I see (sort of, since I don't know Rails). ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Module.html#method-i-define_method).

```
define_method "cancel_#{appointment.id}" do
  # your method body
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `define_method` is best, but one could instead use the version of [Module#class_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-class_eval) which takes a string as an argument:

```
class C
end

x = 'cat'
C.class_eval "def #{x}; 'meow'; end"
C.instance_methods.include?(:cat)
  #=> true
C.new.cat
  #=> 'meow'
```